# strategy for choosing the location of mutex lock and unlock in a multithreading program

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

in the following code snippets, I need to protect connfd, because it can change frequently in `accept()` call.

```
   void *deal_conn(void *arg){
      int connfd;
      connfd = *((int*)arg);
      ....

   }

   for(;;){
     connfd = accept(...);
     pthread_create(&thread, NULL, deal_conn, &connfd);
    }
```

I'm at a loss on where to lock and unlock a mutex for this variable.
can anyone give me some ideas?
thanks!

Comment: connfd is passed as a pointer - for the duration of the deal_conn function that value is subject to change.  Consider using an mt-safe malloc call to create a separate, safe copy of connfd to pass to the deal_conn function.  deal_conn can then free that variable.

Comment: What keeps you from locking just before calling `accept()` and unlocking after having assigned the socket descriptor to the variable local to the thread function?

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass the address of `connfd` to each thread, dynamically allocate a new `int` and pass that and have the thread `free()` it when no longer required. As threads no longer share the same resource no requirement for a mutex:

```
connfd = accept(...);
if (connfd != -1)
{
    int* fd = malloc(sizeof(*fd));
    if (fd)
    {
        *fd = connfd;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, deal_conn, fd);
    }
}

void *deal_conn(void *arg){
   int connfd =  *((int*)arg);

   free(arg);
}
```

Comment: I think there is still problem. although the value of `*fd` will never change, the value of `fd` may change before the thread get its value. isn't it?

Comment: ah,  you meant: even if the new thread is excuted after the next `accept()` returns,  the value of `fd` is already copied to new thread's stack?

Comment: The `fd` is a pointer to dynamically allocated memory. _Only_ the thread to which it is passed has access to the memory allocated.

Comment: I didn't mean the allocated memory it points to, I meant the pointer itself.

Comment: Yes, the address is already passed to the new thread so the next use of fd won't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact I'd also prefer the solution using a dynamically allocated socket descriptor variable as proposed by others, here is an answer to the OP's question:

```
void *deal_conn(void * arg)
{
  int connfd = *((int *) arg);
  /* unlock mutex here */
  ...
}

...

/* init mutex here */

for(;;)
{
  /* lock mutex here */
  int connfd = accept(...);
  if (-1 == connfd)
  {
    /* in case of error unlock mutex here, as the deal_conn() will not be called */
  }
  else
  {
    int result = pthread_create(..., deal_conn, &connfd);
    if (-1 == result)
    {
      /* in case of error unlock mutex here, as the deal_conn() will not be called */
    } 
  }

  ...
```

Comment: I think pthread_create may return before the `deal_conn` get the value from &connfd.

Comment: @user1944267: This is perfectly alright as the accept() loop will block on the call to locking the mutex prior to calling `accept()` as long as the mutex hadn't been unlocked by `deal_conn`.

Comment: I think there is a problem in the code above, do you think so?

Comment: @user1944267: You are referring to what?

Comment: I think there is a problem in the `hmjd`'s code, in his code,  although the value of *fd will never change, the value of fd may change before the thread get its value. isn't it? do you think so?

Comment: @user1944267: *hmjd*'s code is ok, at least referring the handling of the values of `fd` and `*fd` ... ;-) However, it's not a direct answer to your question.

Comment: the new code by `xwlan` seems even better? do you find any mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

how about change the code as followings:

```
 void *deal_conn(void *arg){
          int connfd;
          connfd = (int)arg;
          ....

       }

       for(;;){
         connfd = accept(...);
         pthread_create(&thread, NULL, deal_conn, (void *)connfd);
        }
```

I can't see the necessity to lock connfd, connfd is copied to new thread's stack, not shared by threads.

Comment: wow, seems cool. so even if connfd is 4 bytes, (void *) is 8 bytes, the cast is still OK?

Comment: Use a `intptr_t` typed variable to be passed to `pthread_create()`, as it is guaranteed to be the same size as `void*`.

Comment: ` (void *)(uint64_t)connfd ` is not portable

Comment: @alk, connfd is of int type, not intptr_t, I don't understand your comment

Comment: I forget there's a uintptr_t (pointer sized uint). this should be better

Comment: in fact, FD is typical small, so it's surprising that fd's 31th bit is 1 (hence cause cast issue, 1 is propagated to 32-63th bits for 64 bits code), so it's safe even without first casting it to be a uintptr_t, however, to imply that this can potentially cause cast issue, explicitly cast it to be uintptr_t is a good hint to user.